# how do I set cordovaConfig variables in Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

I am building an app with apache Cordova and in the build.gradle file there are entries like

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION}"
```

or

```
gradleVersion = cordovaConfig.GRADLE_VERSION
```

How do I change these values, or where can I look up the actual values?

In Android Studio, I tried to update the Android Gradle Plugin Version, but I got the following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION is not a valid AGP version string

I changed the value in File->Project Structure->Project from $cordovaConfig.AGP_VERSION to 7.4.2 (Gradle Version in 7.6), but that did not change anything.

Comment: have you tried to edit the config.xml file with preference `<preference name="AndroidGradlePluginVersion" value="the_version_you_need" />`